Trying to install mailman 3 to Ubuntu 24.04 via apt but installation fails
I tried to install mailman3-full package to fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 but the installation fails.
The command I used was plain
apt install mailman3-full
Any ideas how to circumvent the problem?
The installation seems to work quite for long but then there are eror messages (I clipped most of the successful log and started before the real problems started)
dbconfig-common: writing config to /etc/dbconfig-common/mailman3-web.conf
creating database mailman3web.db: success.
verifying database mailman3web.db exists: success.
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django_q/conf.py:174: UserWarning: Retry and timeout are misconfigured. Set retry larger than timeout,failure to do so will cause the tasks to be retriggered before completion.See https://django-q2.readthedocs.io/en/master/configure.html#retry for details.
  warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/django-admin", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('Django==4.2.11', 'console_scripts', 'django-admin')())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/allauth/account/apps.py", line 15, in ready
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware must be added to settings.MIDDLEWARE
ESC[0mdpkg: error processing package mailman3-web (--configure):
 installed mailman3-web package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mailman3-full:
 mailman3-full depends on mailman3-web; however:
  Package mailman3-web is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mailman3-full (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mailman3-web
 mailman3-full
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed


Thank you for any support!

Please add the command you used to the install ...

Used apt install command added

Don't use the distro packages if you want a smooth ride with Mailman3. Please use the virtualenv install: https://docs.mailman3.org/en/latest/install/virtualenv.html
The above link is the official documentation supported by Mailman3 Developers.
Unfortunately, they do not support Distro package installs as indicated at:
https://wiki.list.org/x/12812344

The link I gave is the official documentation supported by the MM3 developers. It will NEVER disappear.

Your objection sounds reasonable. Please make it more clear that you include the information your answer is based on the official information.
